# D3: Most populous areas of a scatter plot

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot

I made a scatter plot with D3. How do I identify most populous areas in the plot and encircle them with an ellipse. For example, there are 2 populous spots at upper right corner of the graph bellow. Is there a function to do it? If not I appreciate for suggestion of 2 things: to identify, and to encircle or any way to mark them.

[Scater plot http://tetet.net/clusterLab/scatter.png](http://tetet.net/clusterLab/scatter.png)

```
var width = 300,
    height = 200;

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height); 

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) console.warn(error);
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(q) {return q.xCoord;}));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(q) {return q.yCoord;}));

    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.xCoord); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.yCoord); })
});
```

Data

```
xCoord  yCoord
0   0
5   3
2   1
4   7
7   4
5   2
9   9
3   4
1   6
5   4
8.1 6.2
8.4 6.6
8   6
8   7
7   8
6.8 8.3
6.4 8.4
6.2 8.3
```

Comment: A simple simple way of thinking about the ellipses, if there aren't many points in each cluster: Go through all pairs of points in a cluster to find the pair of points most distant from each other.  Construct a formula for an ellipse with foci along the line between these two points, e.g. using [these answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate).  Adjust parameters so the ellipse includes all points in the cluster but cannot be made narrower (start with a circle large enough to include both points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a number of clustering algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Algorithms) out there. I'll provide an example with the [OPTICS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm) (I picked it at random, really) and a way to mark points with unique colors per cluster.

Note that I'm using a [**density-clustering**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/density-clustering) package available on npm.

Once we load and parse the data (but before we draw anything on screen) let's setup the algorithm:

```
var optics = new OPTICS(),

    // The algorithm requires a dataset of arrays of points,
    // so we need to create a modified copy of our original data:
    opticsData = data.map(function (d) {
        return [d.xCoord, d.yCoord];
    }),

    // Algorithm configuration:
    epsilon = 2, // min distance between points to be considered a cluster
    minPts = 2, // min number of points in a cluster

    // Now compute the clusters:
    clusters = optics.run(opticsData, epsilon, minPts);
```

Now we can mark the points in our original data with the information of which cluster they belong to. A very crude solution... you might think of something more elegant:

```
clusters.forEach(function (cluster, clusterIndex) {
    cluster.forEach(function (index) {
        // data is our original dataset:
        data[index].cluster = clusterIndex;
    });
});
```

Now let's create a very simple color scale and apply it to our points:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.category20();

// Some code omitted for brevity:
...enter().append("circle")
    ...
    .style('fill', function (d) {
        return colorScale(d.cluster);
    });
```

You can take a look at the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kru1mct/). I had to include the library as is, so you'll need to scroll to the bottom of the JavaScript panel, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want a visual representation, and you do not need to compute a location or center or anything like that, then the solution could be very simple. In addition to your existing circles which represent data points, make each data point draw a translucent larger circle. Where these larger circles overlap the intersection will be darker, and the more that overlap the darker it will get (assuming you keep the background white). You can very the size of the circles, their color and degree of opacity/transparency.